# Is this a good way to encrypt user data?

Tags: security, encryption

I'd like to encrypt the user data I store on my server so that it is safe if my server were to be compromised. Is the following a good way to do it:

Each user's password is the passphrase to a GPG keypair. All the user's data is encrypted using the public key before being saved to the database. The password is discarded and the keypair is kept only for the duration of the session, so the data can only be decrypted when the password is supplied.

Comment: Asymmetric key encryption isn't usually used in this way. Consider using symmetric key encryption.

Answer (score 3):

From the point of view of someone compromising your server, the only way to ensure the data is safe is the way you are doing, when the user have to supply the key to decrypt every time.

Any other technique leaves some weakness that could be exploited.

But you have to be sure the other way (I mean when user provides the password) is secure too, using https and preventions against session attacks, cross scripting and etc.

If you do not have specific hardware to do an extra line of protection as when they are generated pseudo-random numbers based on time (as do the banks tokens) or something like that, the best idea is to keep the keys with the user or to use a third part storage with greater security as the SQL on Azure or Amazon.

I used the same approach after thought a lot about where to put my encrytion keys to make data obscure even if my server got compromised. The only secure way I found was "with the user".

Comment: This leaves you (or, at least, your user) with a problem if the user forgets their password.  It may not be appropriate if the data is something like health records.  If only the one user is supposed to see the data, and you never need to see it at any other time, you're OK.

Comment: I agree, the old issue about security against availability. If that data cannot be lose there must be some failover method, like copying the keys manually to an offline machine or device. Or create some tokens for each user like a pendrive. This "where do a put my encryption key" problem is a very complex problem, that depends on the application and use of the system.

Answer (score 1):

your approach protects you from only 1 attack: stealing your database (and only if you encrypted keys properly). if your server gets compromised they can take your ssl private key and listen your network traffic (with users' keys)