# Encrypting data via client or server or both?

Tags: security, encryption, standards

I have a question concerning data encryption. My question is where do I encrypt the data and why?

FOR REGISTERING

I currently encrypt data in an application/game and send the data to the server to add or update to the database.

FOR SIGNING IN

I ask the server to send me data regarding a username including the password. So I receive the  encrypted password and the username and decrypt the password to see if it matches what the player had inputted.

MY CONCERN

My concern is that someone could intercept what gets sent out and compare it to what they inputted as a password.

My idea for a solution would be to encrypt data on the server as well, but that would only be useful if the server/database was hacked.

I couldn't find anything really specific to my question. I've found articles concerning how to encrypting data, but nothing of the risks and security holes.

I'm also wondering what the standards are concerning this along with the risks of different methods.

EDIT:
I Fear I am over thinking this, but felt it would be safer to ask.

I haven't provided what methods of encrypting data I use because I don't know if that could be a security risk.

Comment: Always encrypt passwords on servers (including salting) by default. That way, they can't be stolen (internally or externally). There are lots of questions on here that are similar, but that are stack-specific and are worth you exploring: eg: [Is there a good way to encrypt user data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834278/is-this-a-good-way-to-encrypt-user-data?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is extremely sensitive, you could go the online backup way (like Mozy, Carbonite, etc) where if you lose your password or private key, you lose your data.

If it's not that sensitive, you just use a master password for all account data, and allow them to reset their password. On the server you only store a random salt and the salted+hashed password, during communication you only send the salt. The client hashes that and you only have to compare the hashed values, so the raw password is never transmitted. Either way, if they hack your server, they can probably get to the master password too, unless you have to insert it to start the app every time. If it's physically separate from the database server, at least with encryption a breach of just that or a hard drive loss won't expose you.

If you're worried about traffic sniffing and hash reuse, which is a possibility if someone wants the account badly enough, you have two good solutions: The better is probably using SSL to connect, which completely eliminates any possibility of exposure, but can require a fair amount of money and setup if you build out to multiple servers. Otherwise you can create a poor man's Diffie-Hellman, like so: With the salt, send another a one-time use key; the client hashes their password with the salt first, then hashes the result with the key and sends it. Server-side, you keep the key in memory or database, and as soon as they're authenticated you forget the key.

You can never defend against keyloggers and rootkits with encryption, though. That needs other security models, like making the user confirm via text message with a new client or IP logs on.

Comment: I like it. A lot of information, but after reading it a few times, things started to hurt less :P  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jcryption.org/

You can use jCryption & OpenSSL library,
jCryption is great javascript library for encryption
you can encryption data in client side and send it to server, in server call openssl library for decryption/encryption,
jCryption is now fully compatible with OpenSSL